# Reading material for technical aspects of timecode and alignment

Tags: video, timecode

I'm a sound engineer with extensive live and recorded experience. My electronics and acoustics are pretty strong IMO but I've never had any extensive interaction with video/film production and post timecode hardware. What's the best book/website/whitepaper to learn the nuts-and-bolts technical aspects of that stuff. Yamaha Sound Reinforcement Handbook gives some discussion of it, but it's short and out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't cover the applications, but it gives a succint view into the nuts and bolts:

[Phil Rees](http://www.philrees.co.uk/articles/timecode.htm)